# Scala, finding max value in arrays

Tags: scala

First time I've had to ask a question here, there is not enough info on Scala out there for a newbie like me.

Basically what I have is a file filled with hundreds of thousands of lists formatted like this:

```
(type, date, count, object)
```

Rows look something like this:

```
(food, 30052014, 400, banana)

(food, 30052014, 2, pizza)
```

All I need to is find the one row with the highest count.

I know I did this a couple of months ago but can't seem to wrap my head around it now. I'm sure I can do this without a function too. All I want to do is set a value and put that row in it but I can't figure it out.

I think basically what I want to do is a Math.max on the 3rd element in the lists, but I just can't get it.

Any help will be kindly appreciated. Sorry if my wording or formatting of this question isn't the best.

EDIT: There's some extra info I've left out that I should probably add:

All the records are stored in a tsv file. I've done this to split them:

```
val split_food = food.map(_.split("/t"))
```

so basically I think I need to use split_food... somehow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modified version of @Szymon answer with your edit addressed:

```
val split_food = food.map(_.split("/t"))
val max_food = split_food.maxBy(tokens => tokens(2).toInt)
```

or, analogously:

```
val max_food = split_food.maxBy { case Array(_, _, count, _) => count.toInt }
```

In case you're using apache spark's RDD, which has limited number of usual scala collections methods, you have to go with reduce

```
val max_food = split_food.reduce { (max: Array[String], current: Array[String]) =>
   val curCount = current(2).toInt
   val maxCount = max(2).toInt // you probably would want to preprocess all items, 
                               // so .toInt will not be called again and again 
   if (curCount > maxCount) current else max 
}
```

Comment: Oh that first one is pretty much exactly what I want I think. Thank you very much. One problem though, I get this error:
error: value maxBy is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[java.lang.String]]

I've had this error before when doing stuff with reduceByKey I think, not sure why it comes up. Any ideas?

Comment: That seems more complicated than what I remember but it still should work. However when I go to do print(max_food) it says that the value isn't found. While running what you posted there, it seems to have aborted the job with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2. I'm almost ready to give up.

Comment: @user3690863 it means that after you loaded your data, and separated it by tab character, at least in one row there are less than 3 entities. Check for the malformed data (maybe some of the records have only type and date or some other fields missing?) OR incorrect usage of separator (maybe your records are delimited with commas, not tabs?)

Comment: As far as I can tell they are all tab delimited only. Definitely appreciate the help though, thanks a lot. I may have to skip this problem.

Comment: I'm still here to help you if you will to continue ;-) You can try `val split_food_lengts = food.map(_.split("/t").length)` in order to see how many tokens in each row.

Comment: That results in 14. I'm not 100% sure why.

Comment: @user3690863, what's the row with 14 look like? You could upload your data if it's not sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `maxBy` function:

```
case class Purchase(category: String, date: Long, count: Int, name: String)

object Purchase {
  def apply(s: String) = s.split("\t") match {
    case Seq(cat, date, count, name) => Purchase(cat, date.toLong, count.toInt, name)
  }
}

foodRows.map(row => Purchase(row)).maxBy(_.count)
```

Comment: Again, thank you very much but check my edit, not sure how exactly to apply this to what I have.

Comment: btw, `type` is a reserved word, as well as `object` -- you can't use them as names without additional hassle

Comment: Yeah that's fine, I was just using the words to describe what's stored in the arrays, they don't actually show up anywhere

Comment: yep, I just saying that Bill class in above example is not compilable

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
case class Record(food:String, date:String, count:Int)
val l = List(Record("ciccio", "x", 1), Record("buffo", "y", 4), Record("banana", "z", 3))
l.maxBy(_.count)

>>> res8: Record = Record(buffo,y,4)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems useful, but could you please check my edit, how will this apply to what I have exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got the answer yet but I had the same issues with maxBy. I found once I ran the package... `import scala.io.Source` I was able to use maxBy and it worked.